# php quoted_printable_decode get html part

Tags: php

I am not able to figure out how to get an HTML out of a simple quoted_pritable_decode command.

Consider the following code from w3schools.

```
$str = "Hello=0Aworld.";
echo quoted_printable_decode($str);
```

The output for this code is:

```
Hello world.
```

However, when I view the source it is:

```
Hello 
world.
```

Well, I am trying to figure out if there is a simpler way to get the second output. I would like to store it in my database in HTML format. I am aware of way arounds like replacing the encoded part, however, is there a recommended way here?

Edit 1:

Both the answers are perfectly fine and a precise explanation from Xavier was great. Since, I just have to mark one as correct, I mark the one which I believe is more precise.

Comment: As i mentioned in my question, I am aware of that answer..I am asking for a recommended approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `nl2br()` encapsulating that when you are storing it into your table.

```
<?php
$str = "Hello=0Aworld.";
echo nl2br(quoted_printable_decode($str));
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to:

```
$str = "Hello=0Aworld.";
echo "<pre>" . quoted_printable_decode($str) . "</pre>";
```

What you echo is being interpreted as pure HTML, and HTML doesn't honor newlines, except when you use  tag. You also could do a `echo str_replace('\n','<br>',quoted_printable_decode($str));` (i.e. AFTER decoding)

Comment: Yes, that would give the correct output. But is there a way to get the HTML?(Except replacing). As I mentioned, I would like to store it in HTML format in my database.

Comment: BTW if you store in the database as HTML make sure you correctly escape your query, or better, use prepared sentences.

Comment: Well, that is pretty cool. However, the problem here is that, when I store it in database it should atleast reflect the "\n" , however, I just don't see any such things to be replaced. I hope, I am clear. It just stores Hello World. and not Hello\nWorld.

Comment: The string is correctly decoded as "Hello\nWorld", the problem is afterwards, when you render it. As you've already seen, when you look at your code you see it as two different lines. Thus, it's HTML not rendering it as you expect.

Comment: Yup, I get it now. So, basically I need to do the processing before storing or echoing it. Thanks a lot..!